# Python: Pymysql hangs without any feedback?

Tags: python, mysql, database, pymysql

First application using Python.

My app is hanging on the pymysql calls, is this library even stable?

Just trying to connect to MySQL database here but every Python package seems horrific to work with? Any other language is very simple and no weird issues.

migrateFresh.py:

```
import pymysql.cursors
import os
import glob
from bootstrap import *

reset_database()
migrate_and_seed()
```

Then I have bootstrap.py:

```
import pymysql.cursors
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import glob

load_dotenv()

def get_connection (database = ''):
    return pymysql.connect(
        host = os.environ.get("DB_HOST"),
        user = os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
        password = os.environ.get("DB_PASS"),
        database = database,
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

def reset_database():
    connection = get_connection()

    with connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(f'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {os.environ.get("DB_NAME")};')
            cursor.execute(f'CREATE DATABASE {os.environ.get("DB_NAME")};')

        connection.commit()

    print('Database has been reset')

def migrate_and_seed():
    connection = get_connection(os.environ.get("DB_NAME"))

    with connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            for f in sorted(glob.glob("migrations/*.sql")):
                print(f)
                with open(f, "r") as infile:
                    query = infile.read()
                    cursor.execute(query)

        connection.commit()

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            for f in sorted(glob.glob("seeders/*.sql")):
                print(f)
                with open(f, "r") as infile:
                    query = infile.read()
                    cursor.execute(query)

        connection.commit()
```

Comment: "My app is hanging on the pymysql calls" - sounds like a lock.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you split your migrate and seed functions and enter the connection context manager separately in each one:

```
import pymysql.cursors
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import glob

load_dotenv()


def get_connection(database=''):
    return pymysql.connect(
        host=os.environ.get("DB_HOST"),
        user=os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
        password=os.environ.get("DB_PASS"),
        database=database,
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)


def reset_database():
    connection = get_connection()

    with connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(f'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {os.environ.get("DB_NAME")};')
            cursor.execute(f'CREATE DATABASE {os.environ.get("DB_NAME")};')

        connection.commit()

    print('Database has been reset')


def migrate_and_seed():
    ok = migrate()
    if not ok:
        print("migration failed. not seeding...")
        return
    ok = seed()
    if not ok:
        print("seeding failed.")


def migrate():
    try:
        with get_connection(os.environ.get("DB_NAME")) as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                for f in sorted(glob.glob("migrations/*.sql")):
                    print(f)
                    with open(f, "r") as infile:
                        query = infile.read()
                        cursor.execute(query)
    
            connection.commit()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print("Migrate Exception:", e)
        return False
    
    
def seed():
    try:
        with get_connection(os.environ.get("DB_NAME")) as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                for f in sorted(glob.glob("seeders/*.sql")):
                    print(f)
                    with open(f, "r") as infile:
                        query = infile.read()
                        cursor.execute(query)
        
            connection.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Seed Exception:", e)
        return False
```

Comment: Why would you recommend this?  How will it fix the behaviour that the OP was experiencing?

Answer (score -2):

The problem is the query, probably DB_USER have not correct privilegies